# Need to change form in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, input

I want to change form input. I want to change look for each element. Every widget should have personal class or id, so something like this will be not a solving:

```html
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Can it be done without using view-export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this in your forms.py:

```
class NameOfYourForm (forms.Form):

    fieldToEdit = forms.CharField (
        max_length = 250,
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "CSSclass"}),
        )
```

You can also update widget attributes this way, by adding this to form clas

```
fieldToEdit.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'CSSclass'})
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: You can't set the ``attrs`` directly in the field, you have to do it in the widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the widget, change the input and add classes directly from the form class:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'input': 'number', 'class': 'SomeClass'})
    )
```